# Distribution of cars among people obeying specific conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

An old man has 9 sons and he owns 81 cars. The first car is worth 1 million dollars, second car is worth 2 million dollars and the 'n'th car is worth 'n' million dollars. Find an effective way to split his 81 cars among his 9 sons such that each son has the same number of cars, and same net worth of cars.

My effort:
I've found that each son needs to receive 9 cars which are worth 369 million dollars in all. I'm totally confused about how to make the distribution thereafter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you wrote all the numbers from 1 to 81 in a square 9 by 9.
Then if you summ the numbers on the diagonal you'll get 73 + 65 + ... + 17 + 9 = 369.
Then shifting diagonal to the right (if you reach the edge of table, go cycle in this row: for example for the first shift of diagonal you'll get 74 + 66 + ... + 18 + 1.
I believe that's what you'are looking for.

P.S. You can have fun with Excel, but nor sure if it's fun...

[image]

Of course, the same algorithm works for finding "fair" distribution in the sense you described for numbers $1,...,n^2$ for any $n$.In our case $n=9$.

Comment: are there any other possible solutions? (other than the diagonals two ways?)